# How do you index a list of namedtuples containing stock info given a range of date?

Tags: python, list, date, namedtuple

```
[Stock(date='2019-11-20', open='150.3100', high='150.8400', low='148.9600', close='148.9700', volume='11291822', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-19', open='150.8800', high='151.3300', low='150.2000', close='150.3900', volume='23935700', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-18', open='150.0700', high='150.5500', low='148.9800', close='150.3400', volume='21534000', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-15', open='148.9300', high='149.9900', low='148.2700', close='149.9700', volume='23485700', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-14', open='147.0200', high='148.4100', low='147.0000', close='148.0600', volume='19729800', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-13', open='146.7400', high='147.4600', low='146.2800', close='147.3100', volume='16919200', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-12', open='146.2800', high='147.5700', low='146.0600', close='147.0700', volume='18641600', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-11', open='145.3400', high='146.4200', low='144.7300', close='146.1100', volume='14362600', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-08', open='143.9800', high='145.9900', low='143.7600', close='145.9600', volume='16732700', indicator=0, signal='', change=0), Stock(date='2019-11-07', open='143.8400', high='144.8800', low='143.7700', close='144.2600', volume='17786700', indicator=0, signal='', change=0)]
```

---

I have a list of namedtuples and I want to index it based on a given range of date. For example, given 2019-11-10 (start_date) and 2019-11-08 (end date), I want to return a list of namedtuples that contains the information only from that date range. How do I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

untested, but something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%Y-%m-%d'
start = datetime.strptime('2019-11-08', format)
end = datetime.strptime('2019-11-10', format)

# concise version
output = filter(lambda tup: start < datetime.strptime(tup['date'], format) < end, your_list_of_tuples)

# verbose version
output = []
for tup in your_list_of_tuples:
  date = datetime.strptime(tup['date'], format)
  if start < date < end:
    output += date
```

note that you had start as the 10th and end as the 8th, which i've assumed was a typo and switched. you might also want >= and <= for the comparisons.

Comment: thank you, i figured it out! Just need to fix up a little bit:  tup.date and output.append(tup)

Comment: cool, glad to help. if this worked for you, please accept it as the answer so others know the question has been answered.